# How do I import a package I have installed from stackage?

Tags: haskell, package, stackage

I am trying to import and use the [prettyprinter](https://www.stackage.org/package/prettyprinter) package. I have installed the package via stack with the following command:

`stack install prettyprinter`

However, I have trouble trying to import this package once I load ghci to try it. I have been taking shots in the dark, such as:

`import prettyprinter`

`import Prettyprint`

`import Data.Text.Prettyprint`

... and so on. Can anyone tell me the right command? Since this is just the latest of many similar experiences, I'd also like to know how I can figure out this command for myself using the information on the stackage page.

Comment: A package defines a set of modules, you can look up the modules, for example in [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter-1.3.0/docs/Data-Text-Prettyprint-Doc.html). Here the module you probably want to import is `import Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc`.

Comment: Also, [you shouldn't normally use `stack install` for libraries](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2018/02/10/an-opinionated-guide-to-haskell-in-2018/#understanding-stacks-model-and-avoiding-its-biggest-gotcha). Use `stack build` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Willem Van Onsem for pointing out that I need to be importing modules, not packages. In this case, `import Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc` was the appropriate choice.

Answer (score 0):

How do you start ghci?

You shouldn't start it directly.

You may try `stack exec ghci`.